# trouble creating an test_app on Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Its showing some error like

[Please help me resolving this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYpDs.jpg)

Comment: run gem install byebug  & then execute bundle install again

Comment: please don't post images of your errors - it isn't very helpful for anyone else who is attempting to search for a solution to a similar issue in the future. Write the relevant information in your question.

Comment: after running gem install byebug    it shows again error                                               ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/Gaurav1111/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.2.0-static/byebug-9.0.6 @Chakreshwar Sharma

Comment: thank you for suggesting @henners66. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: run sudo gem install byebug

Comment: thanks atlast i had to install every gem manually by sudo command. Thanks        @ChakreshwarSharma

Comment: No need sudo for each gem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there because, bundle cannot continue before that specific dependency of I guess something you have in your gemfile is not installed. The error message is quite specific, so follow the on-screen instruction by doing `gem install byebug` and then retry `bundle install`. Bundle is an asynchronous process, hence, some dependencies needs to be installed before others, otherwise it might cause this type of errors. I hope this solves the issue!